# Ajax Slider Control display non-numeric values

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use the [Slider](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Slider/Slider.aspx) control from AjaxControlTookit and my problem is that I cannot find a way to display non-numeric values inside the label bound to the slider. My code is like below..

**Code**:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSlider" runat="server" style="display:none;/>
 <ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="slider1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtSlider" Steps="3"  BoundControlID="lblSliderValue" Minimum="1" Maximum="3" Orientation="Vertical"></ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender>
 <asp:Label ID="lblSliderValue" runat="server" />
```

The `lblSliderValue` only shows me the values of 0,1 and 2, however I would need low, medium and high. So far I haven't found any way to specify these. I tried adding the textbox's `OnTextChanged="txtSlider_textChanged"` `AutoPostBack="true"` and set the `lblSliderValue` in code behind, with no succes. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: I would try creating an array with your values and then let 0 correspond to "low" and show that in your label.

Answer (score 2):

Such functionality doesn't implemented in slider. So let's customize it a bit.
At the first, you need to download toolkit sources. We will modify two files (I'll provide a links to codeplex for these files so you'll easy locate them in solution): [SliderExtender.cs](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a2a6dc6854e0cfb4d11ffa81ad2c2383dfe35086#Server/AjaxControlToolkit/Slider/SliderExtender.cs) and [SliderBehavior_resource.pre.js](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/a2a6dc6854e0cfb4d11ffa81ad2c2383dfe35086#Server/AjaxControlToolkit/Slider/SliderBehavior_resource.pre.js)

Mark the `SliderExtender` class with this attribute: `[ParseChildren(typeof(ListItem), ChildrenAsProperties = true)]`

```
private List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[ExtenderControlProperty]
[ClientPropertyName("items")]
public List<ListItem> Items
{
    get { return items; }
}

static SliderExtender()
{
    if (!ScriptObjectBuilder.CustomConverters.ContainsKey(typeof(ListItem)))
    {
        ScriptObjectBuilder.CustomConverters.Add(typeof(List<ListItem>), SerializeItemsToJson);
    }
}

private static string SerializeItemsToJson(object itemsParam)
{
    var items = itemsParam as List<ListItem>;
    if (items == null)
        return null;

    return "{" + string.Join(",", items.Select(item => string.Format("{0}: '{1}'", item.Value, item.Text))) + "}";
}
```

That's all with server code so let's tweak client side code of extender.

Let's start with JavaScript code. Add to body of `Sys.Extended.UI.SliderBehavior` function this item: `this._items = null;`
And add to prototype of `Sys.Extended.UI.SliderBehavior` function code below:

```
get_items: function () {
    return this._items;
},

set_items: function (value) {
    if (Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(this._items) != value) {
        this._items = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(value);
        this.raisePropertyChanged('items');
    }
}
```

Then, modify the `_calcValue` function as following:

```
_calcValue: function (value, mouseOffset) {
    var val;

    if (value != null) {
        if (!Number.isInstanceOfType(value)) {

            if (this._items) {
                for (var prop in this._items) {
                    if (this._items.hasOwnProperty(prop) && this._items[prop] === value) {
                        value = prop;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
//rest of function's code stays as it is
```

And the last step - fix the `_ensureBinding` function:

```
_ensureBinding: function () {
    if (this._boundControl) {
        var value = this._value;

        var displayItem = this._items && this._items.hasOwnProperty(value) ? this._items[value] : null;

        if (value >= this._minimum || value <= this._maximum) {
            var isInputElement = this._boundControl.nodeName == 'INPUT';

            if (isInputElement) {
                this._boundControl.value = displayItem || value;
            }
            else if (this._boundControl) {
                this._boundControl.innerHTML = displayItem || value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After all changes above, rebuild solution and add reference on toolkit dll to your project. Sample of usage of modified slider here. And it still support two-way binding (i.e. from extender to label but not from bounded textbox to extender).

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Slider1" runat="server" />
<br />
<ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender ID="SliderExtender1" runat="server" BehaviorID="Slider1"
    TargetControlID="Slider1" Minimum="1" Maximum="3" BoundControlID="Slider1_BoundControl"
    Steps="5">
    <Items>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Low" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Medium" />
        <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="High" />
    </Items>
</ajaxToolkit:SliderExtender>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Slider1_BoundControl" />
<%--<asp:Label ID="Slider1_BoundControl" runat="server" Style="text-align: right" />--%>
```

Comment: You'll also need to add `using System.Linq;` to use the `items.Select()` syntax.

Comment: I also found a few problems during compilation of the AjaxControlToolkit that, while aren't strictly related to the question, are useful as a follow-up to this great answer: http://i.ll.do/2011/12/how-to-upgrade-to-new-version-of.html.